# How to use group rights access

Tags: linux, command-line

I don't understand why I can't write into my file. It has write access for a group I'm member of

```
$ ll my_file
-r--rw-r-- 1 myusername editorial 0 Oct 23 14:31 my_file
$echo toto >> my_file
zsh: permission denied: my_file
$ groups
myusername adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare editorial
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output, it appears that you're the file's owner. So you cannot write to the file because it grants only read permission (`+r`) to you.

POSIX file permissions (unlike ACLs) **are not additive**: if you are the owner, you have *only* the owner's permissions, but not those granted to the group or world. (Similarly, group members do not have world permissions either.)